# In oracle on delete set null is not working

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

I have created two tables:

```
Create Table Dept    
(Department_id number Constraint Depart_id_pk Primary Key
,Department_name varchar2(20));

Create table Emp
  (Emp_id number Constraint Empl_id_pk Primary Key
 ,First_name varchar2(10)
 ,salary number
 ,Department_id number
 ,Constraint depart_id_fk Foreign Key (department_id) 
      References Dept (Department_id) on delete set null);
```

Then I have inserted some records in `dept` and `Emp` table. But when I try to drop `dept` table, instead of setting null in `Emp.department_id` column it shows error like this:

```
SQL> Drop Table Dept;
Drop Table Dept
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys
```

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key's clause say "on **delete** set null". Delete is a DML operation, and had you attempted to delete rows from the `dept` table, the corresponding `emp` rows would have been updated with a `null` `dept_id`.

But this isn't the case - you tried to drop the entire table, a DDL operation. This isn't allowed, because you'd be leaving behind constraints on the `emp` table that reference a table that no longer exists. If you want to drop these constraints too, you can use a `cascade constraints` clause:

```
DROP TABLE dept CASCADE CONSTRAINTS
```